# Survey with pictures

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, survey

I was trying to add pictures to my survey form in SharePoint 2013 and I followed all the steps. Then while adding the webpart there was an error as mentioned below:

> Cannot retrieve the URL specified in the Content Link property

Comment: This will  surely help you: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/42607/30145

Comment: Where're the steps that you had followed?